# Can an infinite dimensional Hilbert space be isomorphic to a subspace of itself?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, hilbert-spaces

This question arises in the context of physics for me, so I will admit I am less interested in an exact proof of the statement (and honestly it might be wasted on me). But I wasn't sure of the answer, I want to (be a physicist and) hazard a guess at why it **might** be true, although it is far from rigorous or careful.

If an infinite dimensional vector space $V$ has a countably infinite basis $\{B_i\}$, $i\in\Bbb N$, $B_i\in V$, then $\{B_i\}-B_p$, $p\in \Bbb N$ is also countably infinite and hence these two vector spaces have the same dimensionality and hence are isomorphic however $\text{span}(\{B_i\}-B_p)\perp \text{span}(\{B_p\})$, which seems to imply that $\text{span}(\{B_i\}-B_p)$ is a subspace of $\text{span}(\{B_i\})$.

If my reasoning here is flawed anywhere, I imagine it is either misapplying the "vector spaces of the same dimension are isomorphic" or my potentially false claim that $\text{span}(\{B_i\}-B_p)$ is a subspace of $\text{span}(\{B_i\})$.

Comment: Yes, it's more or less correct. Take, for instance, the space of all $l^2$-sequences $\{a_j\,|\,\,\sum_j a_j^2 < \infty\}$ and a subspace where the first coordinate $a_0$ is zero. Btw you should probably rather say "proper subspace" and "Schauder basis", but that's detail.

Comment: I don't think that OP meant Schauder basis though, they probably meant Hamel basis. There's no indication that the vector space being looked at by OP has any topological structure, so it wouldn't make sense to speak of a Schauder basis.

Comment: @MordeusMorgenstern The indication is in the title. I don't think there is a hilbert space with infinite countable Hamel basis... and the intuition of what he describes seems to more correspond to the other one. But I may be wrong

Comment: Yep, no Banach space has a countable Hamel dimension. That's a consequence of the BCT. However, he seems to be describing just an arbitrary vector space and he seems to be talking about such a vector space having a countable Hamel dimension. I would agree that it would make more sense if OP was talking about a Hilbert space and a Schauder basis. It would be good for OP to give more details on what exactly they are studying (it likely has something to do with QM).

Comment: @PeterFranek Ah I'm sorry, I just saw your edited comment. In that case, the way that OP phrased this question is quite confusing because the argument seems to mostly be focusing on the algebraic span of the basis.

Comment: I will just say again that I am a physicist not a mathematician so the technical aspects of what basis we're talking about is essentially entirely lost on me so I'm sorry but I can't really clarify that further. However this question arises in the context of particle scattering theory, in which we have three "different" (in the sense that they are physically interpreted as distinct) Hilbert spaces, two of them are isomorphic to each other but the third is a subspace of the first two. My question to myself was whether the first two could be isomorphic to the third despite it being "smaller".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every infinite-dimensional Hilbert space is isomorphic to a proper subspace of itself. Your argument is roughly the right idea but you really want an [orthonormal / Hilbert basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthonormal_basis) (possibly uncountable but this doesn't affect the argument) specifically and you want to take the closure of the span or else you won't get Hilbert spaces.

You need to be somewhat careful here about the difference between a Hilbert basis and a [Hamel basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_(linear_algebra)#Hamel_basis). As in the vector space case, it is still true that a Hilbert space is determined up to isomorphism by its "dimension" if "dimension" here is understood as the size of a Hilbert basis, which is generally going to be smaller than the size of a Hamel basis. For example $\ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$ has a countable Hilbert basis (and hence is isomorphic to any other separable Hilbert space, such as $L^2(\mathbb{R})$) but an uncountable Hamel basis. In fact no Hilbert space has a countable Hamel basis.

Comment: Hey Qiaochu, thanks for answering my question. I am confused by your first sentence on re-reading this, if this statement is true, then any finite dimensional vector subspace including the trivial vector subspace is a proper subspace, how can the entire space be isomorphic here?

Comment: @Charlie: the statement should be read "there *exists* some proper subspace isomorphic to the whole space," not "*every* proper subspace is isomorphic to the whole space." If I had intended the universal quantifier I would have written "every proper subspace."

Comment: Ah of course,  apologies, thank you for clarifying I really appreciate your time